# How to Iterate JSON object and display using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to fetch data from API and displaying it on my webpage.
Here is my JS code.

```js
// api url
const api_url = "https://api-url";

async function getapi(url) {
    
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

let tab = 
        `<p>${data.group1.name}</p>`;
        `<p>${data.group1.age}</p>`;
        `<p>${data.group2.name}</p>`;
        `<p>${data.group2.age}</p>`;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tab;

}

getapi(api_url);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

And this is the API format

```js
{
   "group1":{
      "name":"name1",
      "class":"A",
      "age":"19"
   },
      "group2":{
      "name":"name2",
      "class":"B",
      "age":"19"
   },
   ...
}
```

How can i iterate each object and display the values in my webpage. Instead of doing like above.

Comment: Try iterating `Object.keys(data)`

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. What's `A`, and what's `B`?

Comment: I've written that for example.forget to put "" here.

Comment: when i use Object.keys(data) output come with the coma listed, How can i get rid of it ?like group1, group2 and when i use Object.keys(data.group1) it output comes like name1,A.